# Probability With Random Replacement

Tags: probability

A bag contains $3$ red balls, $4$ black balls and $3$ yellow balls. Three balls are drawn at random with replacement from the bag. Find the probability that the balls drawn are all the same colour.

I attempted this question:

P (ALL RED) $= (3/10)^3 = 0.027$

P (ALL BLACK) $= (4/10)^3 = 0.064$

P (ALL YELLOW) $= (3/10)^3 = 0.027$

Therefore, the probability that the balls drawn are all the same colour $= 0.027 + 0.064 + 0.027 = 0.118$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong here. You found the three cases where we could have all three balls be the same color (with replacement), then added them up for the correct final answer.